# How to skip submission of edited data form in editRowGrid on jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using editRowGrid option to edit the jqgrid. I don't want the data to be posted to the server while clicking on submit.

Is there anyway to ignore posting the data to the server and displaying the edited data  on the grid again?

Comment: How does you source code looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `editurl: "clientArray"` parameter, which force *local* editing of data.

Comment: Your answers are really helpful. Your contributions to jqGrid are awesome :) Thank you once again. :)